# How do I tell if a list of strings are found within a larger string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of words (i.e.):

```
['bad', 'good', 'smart']
```

that I need to find which lines in a file that contain **all** those words within that line. I've tried:

```
for line in file_text: 
    if [w for w in list] in line:
        print(line)
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

What is an easy pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: I think the error is pretty self explanatory... you can't use a list to on the left side of `in` when comparing against a string.

Comment: `[w for w in list]` produces the same list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) (or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)):

```
>>> lst = ["the", "fox", "brown"]
>>> sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> all(word in sentence for word in lst)
True
```

Comment: So how can (all) be combined with if statement?

Comment: As simple as that- `if all(word in sentence for word in lst): print sentence`

Answer (score 0):

**One-Liner**

```
for line in file_text:
    [line for w in list if w in line and w == 'smart']
```